# Webpack through yarn: stop process and exit code 1 on warning

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

Running a build process with Webpack, I've got some warnings. I consider some of this warning error, and IMO, it should stop the build process.

```
> yarn build:staging
yarn run v1.10.1
$ webpack --env.staging --env.NODE_ENV=staging
Version: webpack 4.23.1

[...]

[795] ./src/index.css 1.05 KiB {0} [built]
    + 793 hidden modules

WARNING in ./src/assets/banner/3.jpg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js):
Error: Command failed: /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


    at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/execa/index.js:236:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
@ ./src/assets/banner sync ^\.\/.*\.jpg$ ./3.jpg
@ ./src/scenes/home/index.js
@ ./src/router.js
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi babel-polyfill ./src/index.js

[...]

Done in 26.03s.
```

This "warning" should stop the whole process and exit. **Is there a way to tell to webpack with yarn as a driver to stop on certain kind of warning (and return an error code)?** My CI process considers everything is alright, this is not the behavior I expected.

Comment: It's actually an error `error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I understand the error. I don't want to fix it (my question is not about that). I just want to stop building and return an error code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that. You can set the `bail` options to true to exit the process on the first error: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#bail

Comment: @t3__rry Thank you for your answer. Still, bail seems to not fail on warning. Is there a way to fail in warning too? (since the message I got is a warning)

Comment: You could get the `warnings` out of a `Webpack` instance from its `stats` object and then on condition choose to reject/exit the process: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api#stats
Wild guess I never had to do that

Comment: Thank you! You could post your comments as an answer!

Comment: I will thank you @rap-2-h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access `errors` and `warnings` out of a Webpack instance from its `stats` object and then choose to reject/exit the process: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api

For instance:

```
if(stats.errors.length > 0 || process.warning.length > 0) {
  process.exit()
```